# My plugin crashes Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

I built a custom control and an IB plugin for it.  If I run the plugin using IB as a custom executable from the plugin project everything works like a champ.  But if I copy the framework and plugin to the "normal places", create a test app for it, and run the simulator - IB crashes after it returns from the simulator.  I've scoured the web and the docs, but I can't find anything on these methods.  Any idea what I'm missing?  (by the way, the framework is in /Library/Frameworks, and the plugin is in /Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/Interface Builder/Plugins).  Here's the stack from IB's crash report:

Assertion Message: No object for "IBResizeActionInitialFrame" key.

Backtrace:
  0. Interface Builder        0x00004d29 [IBApplication handleAssertion:inFile:onLine:]
  1. InterfaceBuilderKit      0x002c74ee [IBLibraryController createDetailedDescriptionFromTemplate:]
  2. InterfaceBuilderKit      0x003aad22 [NSView lastResizeAction]
  3. Foundation               0x90b98a7a [NSObject valueForKey:]
  4. Foundation               0x90bc65fa [NSObject valueForKeyPath:]
  5. InterfaceBuilderKit      0x0043cec6 [IBResourceManager document]
  6. InterfaceBuilderKit      0x0043d6f9 [IBResourceManager document:willSynchronizeWithProjectFiles:project:]
  7. InterfaceBuilderKit      0x002dfdae [IBDocument willSynchronizeWithProjectFiles:project:]
  8. InterfaceBuilderKit      0x002df00a [IBDocument beginSyncingWithXcodeIfNeeded]
  9. Foundation               0x90baa22e [NSRunLoop runMode:beforeDate:]
 10. CoreFoundation           0x932d6b25 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
 11. CoreFoundation           0x932d6cd8 CFRunLoopRunInMode
 12. HIToolbox                0x92f622c0 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode
 13. HIToolbox                0x92f620d9 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode
 14. HIToolbox                0x92f61f4d BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode
 15. AppKit                   0x95229d7d _DPSNextEvent
 16. AppKit                   0x95229630 [NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:]
 17. Interface Builder        0x0000276b [IBApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:]
 18. AppKit                   0x9522266b [NSApplication run]
 19. AppKit                   0x951ef8a4 NSApplicationMain
 20. Interface Builder        0x00004eca [IBApplication changeInspectorMode:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's the answer to my own question:  If you override `ibDidAddToDesignableDocument`, you must call `super`.  Once I did this, the assertion problem is fixed.  Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hint, I had that exception for weeks before reading your post. This seems have fixed my problem.